Running into crashes whenever I try to compile Go code
Whenever I try to compile go code or inspecting go code, I run into an issue where Ubuntu 24.04 will do one of:

Freeze and I cannot access any of the virtual terminals (pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 does nothing)
htop becomes unresponsive and running any ps command won't work

From dmesg, I saw a few things where it says things like:
[  264.363247] BUG: Bad page map in process compile  pte:8000000304698867 pmd:2d6a7d067
[  264.363254] addr:000000c0015b2000 vm_flags:08100073 anon_vma:ffff8b7bc309a888 mapping:0000000000000000 index:c0015b2
[  264.363257] file:(null) fault:0x0 mmap:0x0 read_folio:0x0
[  264.363287] CPU: 5 PID: 51845 Comm: compile Tainted: P        W  OE      6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu

...

[  264.368183] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:00000000e4660a2f type:MM_ANONPAGES val:1

Or for a full example (hardware name omitted):
[ 4506.522729] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000018
[ 4506.522736] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[ 4506.522738] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[ 4506.522739] PGD 0 P4D 0
[ 4506.522741] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[ 4506.522743] CPU: 4 PID: 44552 Comm: rg Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu
[ 4506.522746] RIP: 0010:utf8nlookup+0x22/0x250
[ 4506.522751] Code: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41 56 41 89 f6 41 55 49 89 fd 41 54 49 89 d4 53 48 89 cb 48 83 ec 08 <48> 8b 47 18 4c 8b 78 30 83 fe 01 0f 87 00 02 00 00 4b 8b 44 f5 08
[ 4506.522753] RSP: 0018:ffffb2059ffc38c0 EFLAGS: 00010286
[ 4506.522755] RAX: 0000000000000040 RBX: ffff92ac4a212118 RCX: ffff92ac4a212118
[ 4506.522756] RDX: ffffb2059ffc3984 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 4506.522757] RBP: ffffb2059ffc38f0 R08: 000000000000007e R09: 0000000000000000
[ 4506.522758] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffb2059ffc3984
[ 4506.522760] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 4506.522761] FS:  0000707219803b20(0000) GS:ffff92bd1ea00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 4506.522762] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 4506.522764] CR2: 0000000000000018 CR3: 000000058a3ee003 CR4: 0000000000f70ef0
[ 4506.522765] PKRU: 55555554
[ 4506.522766] Call Trace:
[ 4506.522768]  <TASK>
[ 4506.522771]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[ 4506.522774]  ? __die+0x24/0x80
[ 4506.522776]  ? page_fault_oops+0x99/0x1b0
[ 4506.522778]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x2e2/0x670
[ 4506.522780]  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
[ 4506.522784]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
[ 4506.522787]  ? utf8nlookup+0x22/0x250
[ 4506.522789]  ? bh_lru_install+0x89/0x140
[ 4506.522792]  utf8byte+0x76/0x480
[ 4506.522794]  ? __pfx_str2hashbuf_signed+0x10/0x10
[ 4506.522796]  utf8_casefold+0x77/0xc0
[ 4506.522798]  ext4fs_dirhash+0x109/0x160
[ 4506.522800]  htree_dirblock_to_tree+0x277/0x360
[ 4506.522804]  ext4_htree_fill_tree+0x289/0x440
[ 4506.522807]  ext4_dx_readdir+0x1f8/0x410
[ 4506.522809]  ext4_readdir+0x5e7/0x780
[ 4506.522811]  iterate_dir+0x111/0x200
[ 4506.522814]  __x64_sys_getdents64+0x84/0x130
[ 4506.522816]  ? __pfx_filldir64+0x10/0x10
[ 4506.522818]  x64_sys_call+0x1b43/0x25c0
[ 4506.522821]  do_syscall_64+0x7f/0x180
[ 4506.522823]  ? do_futex+0x18e/0x260
[ 4506.522826]  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x12a/0x200
[ 4506.522829]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[ 4506.522831]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[ 4506.522833]  ? do_futex+0x18e/0x260
[ 4506.522834]  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x12a/0x200
[ 4506.522836]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
[ 4506.522838]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[ 4506.522840]  ? do_syscall_64+0x8c/0x180
[ 4506.522842]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[ 4506.522844]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[ 4506.522846] RIP: 0033:0x70721cbac0af
[ 4506.522866] Code: eb 03 89 58 08 4c 89 c0 5b c3 53 49 89 f8 8b 47 10 48 8d 77 18 39 47 0c 7c 35 48 63 7f 08 b8 d9 00 00 00 ba 00 08 00 00 0f 05 <48> 89 c3 85 c0 7f 12 79 39 83 f8 fe 74 34 e8 f2 02 00 00 f7 db 89
[ 4506.522867] RSP: 002b:0000707219801760 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000d9
[ 4506.522869] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000070721b0046b0 RCX: 000070721cbac0af
[ 4506.522870] RDX: 0000000000000800 RSI: 000055555642eab8 RDI: 0000000000000007
[ 4506.522871] RBP: 0000000000008000 R08: 000055555642eaa0 R09: 0000000000000050
[ 4506.522872] R10: 000070721c6008c0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000707219801f50
[ 4506.522873] R13: 000070721b0046b0 R14: 000070721b0046b0 R15: 0000707219801ed0

What I did:

Memory test memtest86+x64.efi, ran 5 passes but nothing was found.

Have only a single RAM module from the two I have, use alternative RAM slots (tried every combination)

Tried various kernel versions:

6.8.0-45-generic (seems most stable)
6.8.0-49-generic
6.8.0-31-generic


Set maxcpus=1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT as I heard it could have helped to get more info on the error. However when doing this the problem did not occur.


I also noticed that if I limit the number of cores that Go uses, this issue does not happen as frequently so I'm now setting GOMAXPROCS=5 but this is not ideal.
My next idea is to try a live version but for some reason when trying it crashed. :/
Really looking for help on that one as I'm not sure what I can do at this point.

You are using a tainted kernel, with: A proprietary module; An external compiled module; And an unsigned module. So it can be difficult for us to try to help. without more information, I would assume your issues are with Go itself. As a test, and just as a test, you could try the Ubuntu mainline PPA kernel 6.13-rc1 , but your external module(s) might not exist or load..

Oh sorry! I use nvidia-driver-535. I also checked if when using nvidia-driver-550, the issue wouldn't reproduce but it still does and that driver does not support having different scale for my screens. Thanks for the advice! I'll give that kernel a try
